# When the Littlewood-Richardson rule gives only irreducibles?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, flag-varieties, symmetric-polynomials, littlewood-richardson-coefficients

Given the famous Littlewood-Richardson rule, in terms of Schur polynomials:

$$s_\mu s_\nu=\sum_\lambda c^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu} s_\lambda,$$

is there a classification of the cases where the LR coefficients are equal to 1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**, but this requires some elaboration.

1. [Knutson-Tao-Woodward](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0107011) prove Fulton's conjecture in $\S$6.1. In principle, you can follow the approach by [De Loera-McAllister](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501446) or  [Mulmuley-Narayanan-Sohoni](https://www.emis.de/journals/JACO/Volume36_1/rg1w9655642r84t8.fulltext.pdf), to convert the result into a statement about certain polytopes being single points.
2. [Bürgisser-Ikenmeyer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.2484) make the answer much more explicit, see Prop. 3.13.  Ikenmeyer further generalized this in to $c^\lambda_{\mu\nu}>t$ in [his thesis](https://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/algebra/work/ikenmeyer_thesis.pdf), see Theorem 11.3.2.